# How to specify different access and passwd files for each SVN repository in APACHE

Tags: apache, svn

I am trying to setup SVN with APACHE so that each repository has its own set of .access and .passwd files.

Basically lets take this url: http://svn.thissite.com/repo1  is an address of one of the repository

I have one folder in /var/www/svn/ which contains about 20 different repositories and a set of .access and .passwd files

For the repo1 repository there would be 3 paths relevant:

```
/var/www/svn/repo1 (SVN repository itself)
/var/www/svn/repo1.access (Contains svn access info)
/var/www/svn/repo1.passwd (Contains SVN user and password for that specific repo)
```

I have about 20 repositories + relevant .access and .passwd files

So my question is:
What do I need to write in my APACHE2 config files so that it uses the repository name to access the proper .access and .passwd files? I would like a way of having it simple and not a simple copy paste of 20 blocks of  tags in APACHE if possible.

Thank you!

EDIT:
Content of repo1.access (Starts with [/] for all 20 repos):

```
[/]
Name1 = rw
Name2 = rw
Name3 = rw
```

Content of repo1.passwd (password actually hidden):

```
Name1:XXXXXXXXXX
Name2:XXXXXXXXXX
Name3:XXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have SVN running via Apache on my home server with multiple repositories. I have each repository set up as a Virtual Host, which then lets you specify unique auth and acl files via the `AuthUserFile` and `AuthzSVNAcces` parameters in the config file.

An example Virtual Host for my SVN installation:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.42:80>
        ServerName svn.eidola.its
        DocumentRoot /Istas/Library/WebRoot/

        <Location "/">
                DAV svn
                SVNPath /Istas/Library/Subversion/eidola.its
                SVNPathAuthz off

                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Eidola Repository"
                AuthUserFile /Istas/Library/Config/Subversion/users.basic
                AuthzSVNAccessFile /Istas/Library/Config/Subversion/eidola.acl

                <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
                        Require valid-user
                </LimitExcept>
        </Location>

        Include /Istas/Library/Config/Apache2/svn_rewrite.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

The svn_rewrite.conf file is used to allow me to access the repository directly at the ServerName, or via WebSVN at a rewritten URL. Obviously, that line would not pertain to your situation. :)

Comment: Do you mean I have to create 20 <Location> tags if I want to make it work the way I want?

Comment: Unless you use a scripting language to automate the generation of the virtual hosts, yes. I have 9 virtual hosts for my 9 repositories, each with their own entry in the httpd.conf file. It is a one-time setup though, set and forget! :)